# $ is undefined when loading a MVC 5 project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I try to load a MVC 5 project in Visual Studio 2015 or Visual Studio 2013 and the project immediately throws an unhandled exception when reaching the first section of jquery stating that "0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '$' is undefined".

The project has a jquery file the appropriate folder, there is no repeats of `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")` and all other script files are accounted for. This problem cannot be duplicated on another pc using VS 2013 and the exact same code. I am unsure as to how to proceed.

[The error that keeps popping up when trying to run the project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1vaz.png)

Comment: Check if your bundle is actually loaded. You can do this by pushing F12 and refreshing the page. If you are using chrome, it should appear under "sources".

Comment: It doesnt appear to be listed there...Yet if i go into BundleConfig, the bundle containing the jquery is defined

Comment: So the issue lies in the bundle not being loaded. Make sure that you are calling the bundle correctly and that your solution has the scripts in it's matching folders.

Comment: The bundle is called using the `@Scripts.Render()` method and all the files are in the correct place. Also as mentioned above if i take the code as is and run it on another pc, it runs with no problems

Comment: Hmm, that is really odd... what you could try is remove and re-insert the jquery package. Maybe something went wrong behind the scenes in your project. If indeed everything is as you say it should work and then I have no real other advice than "Turn it off and on again" ;)

Comment: Does your browser disabled javascript?

Comment: I am currently attempting to run it on 3 browsers (IE,Firefox and Chrome) none of them have Javascript disabled :(

Comment: Alas it looks like the old "off and on again" has let me down on this one, still not working :(

Comment: Make sure your jquery is loaded first before your custom javascript files. Make sure to put your script reference inside @section Scripts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as it turns out, I was not looking at the problem broadly enough. I noticed now that the project was not loading its styling or its images either and after a bit of research came across this post which solved the problem

[Loading Web Project in VS2015 -- no styling or images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32212688/loading-web-project-in-vs2015-no-styling-or-images)

The solution was to go to the web.config file and replace

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
  <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

with

```
<system.webServer>
<staticContent>
 <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
<mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
</staticContent>
```

Could anyone please explain to me why this worked? I know its something to do with the new version of IIS.